# Fetching HTML in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am getting started with Angular, and I want to get HTML template from a file using JavaScript, I don't want to use `ng-include` or any other directive as I don't really have an html to play with, I have only JavaScript file with data rendered from `REST` service and I need to send HTML output to the page I am in, so I don't really have any existing elements in the DOM.

So how do I get HTML from another file and use it just from JavaScript, in an Angular way?

Comment: Does your rest generate HTML out put? if so why don't you want to use angular directives? directives are the power of angularjs.

Comment: I am using it inside SharePoint, all I have is a link from the page to JavaScript file, so I can't just add HTML to the page, I need to fetch html from another page and draw my output using JavaScript.

Comment: Now I'm getting confused. $compile also works fine as suggested. I'd request you to put some code so we can help you out.

Comment: Let me rephrase it. How do I get HTML from another page and store it in a variable inside my JS file using Angular? What do I do? `var returnedHTML = ???`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use directive and as James point out use the $compile.
You can look some doc https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler

If for any reason you don't want to do that, I can put an exemple of a really **BAD** angular code I use on my app to show the CGU (an HTML from another domain).

Note that we use jQuery, and that's not a good thing in Angular world.

```
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'URL_HTML'
  }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    var html_from_server = $.parseHTML(data);
    data = $(html_from_server.find('#container'));//look for the content of an ID.
    $('#content_cgu').html(data.html());// get an element on our page and replace the html content
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) - it sounds like that's what you're looking for. You can take the html from your service and compile it to work in your AngularJS application.

Comment: Thanks James, but before I do the compile, how do I get the HTML in Angular? Is there any example?

Comment: You can use $http to pull in external data to Angular: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http - there are some good examples online - probably not the sort of thing you're doing, but should be enough to get started.

Answer (score 0):

> Let me rephrase it. How do I get HTML from another page and store it in a variable inside my JS file using Angular? What do I do? var returnedHTML = ???

Straightforward solution:

```
var returnedHTML;
var url = 'http://www.google.com';
$http.get(url, { cache: $templateCache }).then(function(result){
   returnedHTML = result.data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just dealing with this today. I think your question was misunderstood.

You simply include an ng-include into your code like so:

```
ng-include="'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random'"
```

Angular will display your URL as directly in the page.